# Remove comma inside quoted string in a comma separated list

Tags: php, string, double-quotes

I have a string

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,"6,000",7,8,9';
```

How can I clean it up to:

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6000,7,8,9'
```

Comment: str_replace(find,replace,string,count)

Comment: @Satya You could show as an example, that removes the comma within quotes, but _not_ the ones outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (for PHP < 5.3):

```
$dst = array();
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,"6,000",7,8,9';

$state = false;
$buffer = '';
for ($i = 0, $lim = strlen($str); $i < $lim; $i += 1) {
  $char = $str[$i];

  switch ($char) {
    case ',':
      if (!$state) {
        $dst[] = $buffer;
        $buffer = '';
      }
      break;

    case '"':
      $state = !$state;
      break;

    default:
      $buffer .= $char;
  }
}

$dst[] = $buffer;

print_r($dst);
```

Comment: this works like a magic, thanks Yoshi. also thanks for Satya and KingCrunch.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/str-getcsv

```
$items = str_getcsv($str);
$items = array_map (
  function ($item) { str_replace(',', '', $item); },
  $items;
);
```

Now if you like you can merge them together again

```
$str = implode(',', $items);
```

Comment: it appears that str_getcsv() function only runs at PHP 5.3.0 or greater, im still using 5.2.6 need to upgrade my php installation first

Comment: Yes, you need to. 5.3 is nearly 3 years old and 5.4 is out for some weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,"6,000",7,8,9';
$pattern='/"(\d+),(\d+)"/';
$replacement='${1}$2';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str );
```

Thanks:-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,"6,000",7,8,9';
echo $str;
echo str_replace('"','',$str);
?>
```

Comment: outputs `1,2,3,4,5,6,000,7,8,9`. Not really what was asked for, is it?

Comment: I think so Yoshi, let us wait for naboen to reply